# Python3 Support on Volttron

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, startup, volttron

It appears that Python 2.7 (which is now officially no longer supported) is required by the bootstrap.py document for Volttron (see line 348). Does this indicate that Volttron as a platform does not operate on a any supported versions of Python? Or is this tangential to operation of the platform in general? And if so is there a way to setup Volttron using Python3 without modifying the codebase?

https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron

Comment: The bit of docs I've been able to quickly find indicates Voltron does indeed support Voltron 3.  You may want to expand your search to look for a Voltron version that supports Python 3.  This doc, for instance, shows support for Python using pip3 on Ubuntu: https://github.com/snare/voltron/wiki/Installation

Comment: Voltron appears to support Python 3, I'm not sure what the issue/your question is.

Comment: To clarify earlier post inaccurately had voltron not volttron in the question. The two above comments are in reference to voltron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7.0rc1 release of VOLTTRON supports python3. Please see https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/releases/tag/7.0rc1. This release was tested with python 3.6. This release still has a few outdated documentation but the installation instructions have been updated. There is going to be a new 7.0rc3 release with updated documentation and few more features in the next few days. The develop branch is the latest version of the code that has been tested with python 3.7. Please try out 7.0rc1 or develop branch and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I was able to get 7.0rc1 up and running with python3.

Comment: @ChrisBriere if this answer helped you then you need to accept it so that chandrika can receive the appropropriate points.